# SYNONYM в SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Почитал статью о синонимах: http://sql-language.ru/create-synonym.html

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы все объекты при создании пользователем  были доступны и другим пользователям без применения синонимов?

Нашел статью https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569453/create-synonym-to-all-tables-in-a-different-database-with-a-script

Это что получается, этот скрипт нужно запускать, когда создается новый объект в системе?

Comment: Да.​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Чем вас этот способ не устраивает?

Comment: неудобно  после каждого создания таблиц запускать этот скрипт..

Comment: Вы каждый день таблицы создаёте что ли? Выполнить один `exec` при создании таблицы — не так уж сложно. Если используете миграции для обновления таблиц в вашем любимом языке программирования, то можно прицепиться к миграциям, собственно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Синонимы — простое и топорное средство, которое не предполагает хранение сложной логики генерации синонимов для всех объектов в БД. Если нужна логика, то просто пишется скрипт.

За пример можно взять [хранимую процедуру из ответа к приведённому вами вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3571691). При наличии такой процедуры достаточно вызывать её в одну строчку при каждом обновлении БД, которое может затронуть синонимы.

Если вы не пишете и запускаете скрипты вручную, а полагаетесь хоть на какую-то автоматику, например, на библиотеку миграций в вашем любимом языке программирования, то можно избавиться и от необходимости вызывать эту одну строчку вручную — достаточно прицепиться к миграциям и вызывать процедуру после миграций.